# Domain Model different user levels implemting on json database

Tags: json, database, oop

Below i have the domain model which i think is correct. Im trying to implement this on a json database but i am not sure am i on the right track. From what im reading about json there is no relations between the objects how do i link the objects.

As you can see there is 2 different types of users, a user with 1 vehicle and 1 driver. There is also a manager user with multiple vehicles and multiple drivers.

Could anyone tell me if im on the right track.

Im using firebase so i have to use json.

[image: Domain model]

Answer (score 0):

In a document-based or object-oriented database, what was previously a *relation* in a relational databse is converted into [*associations*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Association_%28object-oriented_programming%29) (you might want to read about [aggregation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_composition#Aggregation) too):

- A 1-1 association is just a property holding the other side of the association. A customer has a profile, and a profile is owned by a customer.
- A 1-n association is represented by a collection. In JSON it would be an *array* of associated object. For example, *an order has many order lines*.
- A m-n association is represented by a collection on both sides of the associated objects. For example, *many questions are written by many authors*.

BTW, if you strictly go for this approach, you would end up having a single aggregate root (the top-most object in your model) and this would be very harmful and most NoSQL databases have nesting and per-object storage limits.

Therefore, you need to store all objects that can live alone from others in separate collections (collections concept maps to tables in the relational world), and those ones that are always associated to others and won't be directly queried won't own their own collections. For example:

- A customer may own its own collection.
- An order line can't live outside an order. You may never query all order lines of all orders at once...